# Average number of exchanges during first partition stage in Quicksort

Tags: algorithm-analysis, asymptotics, quicksort

**I am trying to understand average no of exchanges in Quicksort.**

Here is the code to partition the array -

```
 private static int partition(double[] a, int lo, int hi) {
        int i = lo;
        int j = hi + 1;
        double v = a[lo];
        while (true) { 

            // find item on lo to swap
            while (less(a[++i], v))
                if (i == hi) break;

            // find item on hi to swap
            while (less(v, a[--j]))
                if (j == lo) break;      // redundant since a[lo] acts as sentinel

            // check if pointers cross
            if (i >= j) break;

            exch(a, i, j);
        }

        // put v = a[j] into position
        exch(a, lo, j);

        // with a[lo .. j-1] <= a[j] <= a[j+1 .. hi]
        return j;
    }
```

To start with in first partition stage -

There are total comparisons as below $ C_N= N +1 $

so exchanges in worst case should be  $ \frac{N}{2} - 1 $

But am not able to deduce number of exchanges in first partition
stage which is  $ \frac{(N-2)}{6} $

**can someone explain how to deduce this?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The partition method in the question, `partition(a, lo, hi)` is called [Hoare’s partition scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Hoare_partition_scheme), which is the most classic partition scheme used in quicksort.

Here is the situation. There are $n$ numbers that are non-equal pairwise. Array $a=(a_0, a_1, \cdots, a_{n-1})$ is a uniformly-random permutation of those $n$ numbers. We will run the method `partition(a, 0, n-1)`. What is the number of exchanges executed inside the loop `while(true)`? (Note that the exchange `exch(a, lo, j)` outside the loop is not counted.)

WLOG, let the $n$ numbers be $1, 2, \cdots, n$.

Suppose the first element of $a$ is $p$ (for **p**ivot). Excluding that first element, split $a$ into one segment of $p-1$ numbers followed by another segment of $n-p$ numbers.

$$a = (p,\ \underbrace{a_1,\ a_2,\ \cdots,\ a_{p-1},}_{p-1\text{ numbers}}\ \ \underbrace{a_p,\ a_{p+1},\ \cdots\ a_{n-1}}_{n-p\text{ numbers}})$$

Observe the number of elements greater than $p$ in the front segment is always the same as the number of elements smaller than $p$ in the back segment. (Proof: let the two numbers be $x$ and $y$ respectively. The total number of elements greater than $p$ in $a$ is $x + ( n-p-y)$. On the other hand, the total number of numbers greater than $p$, which are $p+1, p+2, \cdots, n$, is $n-p$. That means, $x+(n-p-y)=n-p$, which means $x=y$.)

In the while loop of `partition(a, 0, n-1)`, the first element greater than $p$ in the front segment is exchanged with the last element smaller than $p$ in the back segment. Then the second element greater than $p$ in the front segment is exchanged with the second last element smaller than $p$ in the back segment. And so on, until we have exhausted elements greater than $p$ in the front segment (and, in the meantime, we have exhausted elements smaller than $p$ in the back segment as well). So the number of exchanges made is equal to the number of elements greater than $p$ in the front segment.

To calculate the average number of exchanges made, let us run `partition(a, 0, n-1)` as $a$ ranges over all permutations of $1, 2, \cdots, n$. Then

$$\text{total number of exchanges}=\sum_{p=1}^n\sum_{a_0=p}\text{number of exchanges on }a\\
=\sum_{p=1}^n\sum_{x}^{}x\cdot(\text{number of permutations that starts with }p\text{ 
 with }x\text{ exchanges performed})$$

As we have explained above, for a permutation that starts with $p$, $x$ exchanges will be performed on it if and only if that permutation has $x$ elements greater than $p$ in its front segment of $p-1$ elements. The number of such kind of permutations is the product of the following four factors.

$$
\underbrace{\binom{n-p}{x}}_{\text{the number of ways to choose }\quad\ \  \\x\text{ elements out of all }n-p\\\text{numbers that are greater than }\ \\p \text{ for the front segment}} 
\underbrace{\binom{p-1}{p-1-x}}_{\text{the number of ways to chose }\\p-1-x\text{ elements out of all}\\p-1 \text{ numbers that are smaller }\quad\ \ \\\text{than }p\text{ for the front segment}} 
\underbrace{(p-1)!}_{\text{the number of ways}\\\text{to permute all }p-1\\\text{elements in the}\\\text{front segment}}\quad\ \
\underbrace{(n-p)!}_{\text{the number of ways}\\\text{to permute all }\\n-p\text{ elements in}\\\text{the back segment}}\\
$$

So,

$$\begin{aligned}&\quad\text{total number of exchanges}\\
&=\sum_{p=1}^n\sum_{x=0}^{\min(n-p, p-1)}x\binom{n-p}{x}\binom{p-1}{p-1-x}(p-1)!(n-p)!\\
&=\sum_{p=1}^n\left((p-1)!(n-p)!\sum_{x=0}^{\min(n-p, p-1)}x\binom{n-p}{x}\binom{p-1}{p-1-x}\right)\\
&=\sum_{p=1}^n\left((p-1)!(n-p)!\sum_{x=1}^{\min(n-p, p-1)}(n-p)\binom{n-p-1}{x-1}\binom{p-1}{p-1-x}\right)\\
&=\sum_{p=1}^n\left((p-1)!(n-p)!(n-p)\sum_{y=0}^{\min(n-p-1, p-2)}\binom{n-p-1}{y}\binom{p-1}{p-2-y}\right)\\
&\stackrel{\bigstar}{=}\sum_{p=1}^n(p-1)!(n-p)!(n-p)\binom{n-2}{p-2}\\
&=\sum_{p=1}^n(p-1)(n-p)(n-2)!\\
&=(n-2)!\left((n+1)\sum_{p=1}^np-\sum_{p=1}^nn-\sum_{p=1}^np^2\right)\\
&=(n-2)!\left((n+1)\frac{n(n+1)}2-n^2-\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6\right)\\
&=n-2)!\,\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}6=n!\,\frac{n-2}6.\\
\end{aligned}$$

The average number of exchanges is
$$\frac{\text{total number of exchanges}}{\text{number of permutations}}
=\frac n6-\frac13 \color{#d0d0d0}{\quad\text{for } n\ge2}.$$

---

You might wonder the equality above that is marked with a $\bigstar$. It can be established by splitting into two cases, when $n-p-1\lt p-2$ and when $n-p-1\ge p-2$, and then using [Vandermonde's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity).

Another way to prove it uniformly is to rewrite the Vandermonde's identity as, for any
non-negative integer $m, n, k$, 
$$\sum_{r=-\infty}^{\infty}\binom{m}{k}\binom{n}{r-k}=\binom{m+n}{r},$$
where we extend the definition of the binomial coefficient $\binom nk$ so that for all $n\ge0$ we have $\binom nk=0$ for all $k\lt 0$ or $k\gt n$. Note that the summation on the left-hand-side ranges is well-defined, since it contains, in fact, only finitely many non-zero items. We have,
$$\sum_{y=0}^{\min(n-p-1, p-2)}\binom{n-p-1}{y}\binom{p-1}{p-2-y}=\sum_{y=-\infty}^{\infty}\binom{n-p-1}{y}\binom{p-1}{p-2-y}\\=\binom{(n-p-1)+(p-1)}{y+(p-2-y)}=\binom{n-2}{p-2}.$$

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation.